# Is it a good idea to use sqlite3 in-memory mode as cache in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

In python we can create an in-memory sqlite3 connection:

`import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3(':memory:')`

So is it a good idea to use it as a in-memory cache database? Especially in small or medium scaled cases?

I'm not sure about the sqlite3 module is written in Python or C or something else, so I'm not sure about the memory efficiency and performance either.

Usually redis performs good as a cache DB, but it makes the app much heavier and brings more work on management...

Also, other alternative solutions are welcomed, as long as they're light enough.

Comment: Dictionary, perhaps?

Comment: If you run multiple processes of the same Python code (such as in a wsgi container) you will end up with multiple independent copies of your database. It is a good idea to keep it separate, as in Redis.

Comment: Do you need SQL? If so, sqlite3 makes sense. I've used in-memory sqlite3 as a cache in front of on-disk sqlite3, because it's dead simple to move queries back and forth between the two, and it works pretty well at the small-to-medium scale (as in the kind of scale where sqlite3 makes sense for your persistent storage…). On the other hand, if you just need a key-value store, wrapping it in a relational database and generating and parsing SQL is just unnecessary complexity in your code and overhead in your runtime.

Comment: "I'm not sure about the sqlite3 module is written in Python or C" Have you tried looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)? The very first sentence begins "SQLite is a C library…" But really, for a database engine handling smallish tables, raw processing power isn't that important in the first place. If you want to know whether something is efficient enough, guessing what language it's written in isn't very useful; build a benchmark that approximates your use and run it.